# Fantasy league tracker for Game of Thrones

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

So I've just started learning about MySQL and PHP to create a fantasy league tracker for Game of Thrones for my office. I got it to technically work fine, but I think it's way clunkier than it has to be, with a lot of repeated code, and I'd like to know how to clean it up and streamline things.

I'd also ideally like to find a way to sort the tables by the final points tally, which I just don't see as possible the way I have it set up. The code that is here is only for one player and their chosen characters, but there would be about 9 other players. All of that info is in the database where the characters and players share an id to match them up.

Here's the PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Cosmic Game of Thrones</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "cosmicgot.dev";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "gameofthrones";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT a.name,a.active,a.survived,a.dead,a.killer,b.playername, a.player_id FROM characters AS a LEFT JOIN player AS b ON a.player_id = b.player_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

#Andrew
echo "<h1>". "Andrew". "</h1>";
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr><td>Character</td><td>Active</td><td>Survivor</td><td>Dead</td><td>Murderer</td><td>Total</td></tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $row["killer"] = $row["killer"] * 10;
    $row["survived"] = $row["survived"] * 10;

    if($row['player_id'] == 1) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>";

        if ($row['active'] == 1) {
            echo "<td>" . "Active" . "</td>";
        }
        if ($row['active'] == 0){
            echo "<td>" . "Not Active" . "</td>";
        }

    echo "<td>" . $row["survived"] . "</td>";

    if ($row['dead'] == 0) {
            echo "<td>" . $row['dead'] . "</td>";
        }
    if ($row['dead'] == 1) {
            $row['dead'] = $row['dead'] - 11;
            echo "<td>" . $row['dead'] . "</td>";
        }

    echo "<td>" . $row["killer"] . "</td>";

    $totals = $row["killer"] + $row["survived"] + $row["dead"];
    echo "<td>" . $totals . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    }
}
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here are the schemas

```
USE gameofthrones;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS player;
CREATE TABLE player
(
    player_id               int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, #unique player id
    playername      varchar(40) NOT NULL, #player name

    PRIMARY KEY     (player_id)
); 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS characters;
CREATE TABLE characters
(
    name            varchar(40) NOT NULL, #character name
    active          tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL, #char active status
    survived        smallint unsigned NOT NULL, #char alive status
    dead            smallint unsigned NOT NULL, #char dead status
    killer          smallint unsigned NOT NULL, #char killed amount
    player_id       int unsigned NOT NULL, #assign player id to character

    PRIMARY KEY     (name)
);
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  I changed your title to the description of your code that you put in the body.  We generally title things based on what the code does, not on what we want out of a review.  Feel free to edit it again if it's not quite right.  You also may want to describe what a "Game of Thrones fantasy league tracker" does.  It's not clear to me from that description.  A problem statement saying something like "This code is supposed to..." could clarify things.  As few as one or as many as five paragraphs would be fine.